# When I build an element and insert it into the DOM, I have no margin

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to build a list. Each newly built row should have input field and a button next to it. When I build and insert this line with javascript there is no margin between the input field and the button. If I insert the built HTML static into the list there is a margin between input field and button. Why is that? And what do I have to do to make it behave the same as when I copy it statically into the dom?

```js
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.addNewChoice');
const fieldsContainer = document.querySelector('#fields');
let count = 1;

function addNewChoice() {
  count++;
  const newFieldWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  
  newFieldWrapper.classList.add('mt-10');
  const newFieldInput = document.createElement('input');
  const removeBtn = document.createElement('button');
  newFieldInput.setAttribute('name', 'poll-choice-' + count);
  newFieldInput.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Choice ' + count)
  removeBtn.textContent = 'X';
  removeBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'removeItem(this)');
  newFieldWrapper.appendChild(newFieldInput);
  newFieldWrapper.appendChild(removeBtn);
  fieldsContainer.appendChild(newFieldWrapper);
}

function removeItem(ev) {
  console.log('remove');
}
```

```css
.mt-10 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="fields" class="hidex">
    <input name="poll-name" placeholder="title">
    <div class="mt-10">
      <input name="poll-choice-1" value="" placeholder="Choice 1">
      <button class="addNewChoice" onclick="addNewChoice()">+</button>
    </div>
    

  </div>
</div>
```

And here the generated HTML with Javascript:

```html
<div class="mt-10"><input name="poll-choice-2" placeholder="Choice 2"><button onclick="removeItem(this)">X</button></div>
```

Comment: the reason it's because those are inline elements and take into accounts also text nodes for their positioning. Since there's a new line between the input and the button elements, that will be enough to create that space you see. To believe it, try to edit your html putting those tags next to each other. So you might try `display: inline-block` or a different kind of layout

Comment: This isn’t margin, this is white space. You have one line break and six space characters between your original elements which are collapsed to one space by HTML. Simply add a `newFieldWrapper.append(" ");` in between. Consider using [`<template>`s](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you Sebastian. I had actually briefly considered building it as a web component. I could also work with the template tag. Is that the direction you mean?  Can you please show me how you would have done it with the template? Thanks to you!